# Problems using Gluon Charm's Alert

Tags: mobile, alert, gluon, gluon-mobile

I understand that JavaFX's Alert cannot be used yet with mobile apps. But what about the Gluon Charm Alert?

I have defined a Gluon Mobile MultiView FXML project. I've updated the gradle project's dependencies to include charm-2.2.0.jar, so the Gluon Charm Alert class is available. In order to use it, you also need access to javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType.

I don't seem to have compile-time access to the above AlertType class.

I'm using NetBeans 8.1 with the most recent Gluon/Gradle plug-in on a Mac with OS X 10.11.14. Is there an additional configuation dependency I must define?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.capitals.Capitals'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:2.2.0'
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-android:2.2.0'
    iosRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-ios:2.2.0'
    desktopRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-desktop:2.2.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.asgteach.capitals.**.*',
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'io.datafx.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access JavaFX `Alert.AlertType` class, without the need of adding any dependency.

Make sure you are using the latest version of the jfxmobile plugin (1.0.8).

This works on desktop and mobile:

```
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Alert;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class BasicView extends View {
  public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);
    Button button = new Button("Show alert");
    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "This is an Alert!");
        alert.showAndWait();
    });
    setCenter(new StackPane(button));
  }
}
```

If it isn't the case for you, post your build.gradle and any exception you may have.

Comment: Thank you, José, for your quick response. Indeed, the code you posted runs with no problem. However, NetBeans gives me a red-line compilation error with the message: "The type of Alert(AltertType,String) is erroneous. The package javafx.scene.control.Alert does not exist."

Comment: You should be able to run both JavaFX and Gluon's Alert. What is your JDK? JavaFX Alert is available since 8u40, but Gluon already bundles 8u60.

Comment: JDK according to NetBeans Java Platform is jdk1.8.0_74.jdk.

Comment: If you check your imports, you'll see you are using other JavaFX classes, without a red mark for them. I've edited my answer with the imports for the view, without any warnings (NetBeans 8.1, Mac OX 10.11.14, JDK 8u92). Try to create a regular JavaFX project in NetBeans, add an Alert and see if still in red.